Yaml Scripting solution needed
I'm using azure DevOps for deployment to salesforce platform. using Yaml scripting, i have created a stage for validation, is it possible to hold the pipeline for triggering the next stage which is deployment until i merge the pull request in azure repos ?
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')) 

I have used the above condition but the pipeline is not waiting for me to the merge the pull request.

Hi @sai rohith, what's the latest state of the issue after trying my suggestion?


is it possible to hold the pipeline for triggering the next stage which is deployment until I merge the pull request in azure repos?

No, not using the same build (i.e. same run).
You can use conditions/triggers to run the validation stage when validating the pull request and then trigger the deployment after changes are merged; or, as an alternative, create one pipeline for the validation and another one for the deployment.

I have used the above condition but the pipeline is not waiting for me to the merge the pull request.

As mentioned in Build variables (DevOps Services), variable Build.Reason has value PullRequest when the  build is triggered by a Git branch policy that requires a build. This happens before pull request changes are merged.

hi @Rui Jarimba, thank you for the response.


is it possible to hold the pipeline for triggering the next stage which is deployment until i merge the pull request in azure repos

No. If your pipeline is triggered by a PR, the above is not possible. Once you complete your PR, the validation pipeline will be canceled and your deployment stage will not run.
As a workaround, it's suggested that you run your validation in a pipeline and deployment in another pipeline. Use webhook to trigger your deployment pipeline when PR is completed. Refer to the steps below.

Create a webhook
Go to Project Settings -> Service Hooks -> Plus button -> Select Web Hooks -> Next -> Trigger on this type of event: Pull request updated -> Select your Repository and Target branch -> Next -> Set URL: https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview -> Finish.



Create an Incoming Webhook service connection.

WebHook Name: The name of the webhook should match webhook created above.
Service connection name: Assign a name to your SC.



Configure webhook to trigger your deployment pipeline.
Use filters to ensure the pipeline will only be triggered when PR is completed.


trigger:
- none

resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: PRCompleted          ### Webhook alias
      connection: WebhookTrigger    ### Incoming webhook service connection
      filters:
        - path: resource.status
          value: completed

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:
    - script: echo 'Deployment'

See more info from Generic webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines.

hi @Ziyang Liu-MSFT, thank you for the response. i will check this workaround

Feel free to try it and let me know if you need help.
